# Subfigure - Missing number

Tags: subfloats

I have a problem. I want to include 3 figures via subfigures. I want the first pic to be alone in the center and the second and third fig to be beneath. This is my code:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
    \centering
    \subfigure[First caption]
    {
        \includegraphics[width=0.39\textwidth]{82.pdf}
        \label{fig:first_sub}
    }
    \\
    \subfigure[Second caption]
    {
        \includegraphics[width=0.39\textwidth]{82.pdf}
        \label{fig:second_sub}
    }
    \subfigure[Third caption]
    {
        \includegraphics[width=0.39\textwidth]{82.pdf}
        \label{fig:third_sub}
    }
    \caption{Common figure caption.}
    \label{fig:sample_subfigures}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

The problem is that I get an Error: "! Missing number, treated as zero." After my first pic and I don't know why...
Maybe you guys can help me. I'd appreciate it.

Comment: What package are you using to include your `\subfigure`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you use obsolete package `subfigure`. Instead it try to use for example `subfig` which is replacement for it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

    \begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
    \centering
    \subfloat[First caption]
    {
        \includegraphics[width=0.39\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \label{fig:first_sub}
    }
    \\
    \subfloat[Second caption]
    {
        \includegraphics[width=0.39\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \label{fig:second_sub}
    }
    \subfloat[Third caption]
    {
        \includegraphics[width=0.39\textwidth]{example-image-c}
        \label{fig:third_sub}
    }
    \caption{Common figure caption.}
    \label{fig:sample_subfigures}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

It gives:

[image]

**Addendum:**  Another better possibility -- as said Torbjørn T. in his comment -- is to use package `subcaption`. Considering it above code become:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

    \begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
    \centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}\centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{First caption}
        \label{fig:first_sub}
\end{subfigure}
    \\
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}\centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Second caption}
        \label{fig:second_sub}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.33\textwidth}\centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-c}
        \caption{Third caption}
        \label{fig:third_sub}
\end{subfigure}
    \caption{Common figure caption.}
    \label{fig:sample_subfigures}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Obtained image is (almost) the same as before.

Comment: Judging by the error message I would say he/she has `\usepackage{subcaption}` in the preamble, but is clearly using the syntax of the `subfigure` package. `subcaption` works better with `hyperref` for example, so changing the syntax to using its environment/macro is possibly a better option.

Comment: I will added option with `subcaption`. I regularly use `subfig` without any problems, however with option `caption=false` in memoir` document class (so I actually use memoir captions system).

Comment: Actually, seems I should correct myself. The manual of `subfig` states that it works correctly with `hyperref`, so perhaps this was only a problem with older versions.

Comment: I just tried the second possibility and it just works fine!

Comment: @TorbjørnT. No, unfortunately the `hyperref` problems of `subfig` were never fixed :-( There is an adaption to `hyperref` included in `subfig`, therefore the documentation claims it works correctly, but unfortunately there are bugs in the adaption. I have sent fixes to Steven, and he had planned to integrate them into version 1.4 of the `subfig` package, but unfortunately he never published it.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Aha, I see. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt, temporary version of `subfig` (version 1.3)  is from 2005,; Is that means that package is not maintained anymore?

Comment: @Zarko I don't know. https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig lists Vafa Kha­lighi as maintainer, but I haven't seen any maintaining in forums or any contribution to the `subfig` package from him so far beside https://www.tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2010-May/016551.html .